# Xubuntu 20.04: cannot login into my account!

Tags: xubuntu, login, 20.04

Good day! During my session something went wrong. My wifi connection suddenly switched off so I restarted my notebook. After which I cannot login into my account on Xubuntu 20.04. The system now requires password but does not accept it. How to cure the problem? All advices are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell here what actions your PC was doing during the loss of WiFi-connection ?
If connection is lost during an upgrade, then sometimes the keyboard definition falls back to *US-international lay out*.
So my advice: try to enter your password as if your keyboard was a US-international. Hopes this helps...

From your question i assume you only have ONE account created in this Xubuntu-installation. Otherwise: try to log in using the other login-account you created. Is this possible ?

Can you log in using the guest account ?

Wim